# Android MediaPlayer error with intent and button

Tags: android, button, android-intent, audio-player

Basically I have my main activity that, through an intent, calls another activity that has a button that should play a sound.

That said, in the second activity I have this method:

```
public void start_sound(View v) {
    String url = /*"MY_URL"*/;
    try {
        if (mp != null)
        {
            mp.stop();
            mp.release();
            mp = null;
        }
        mp = new MediaPlayer();
        mp.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        mp.setDataSource(url);
        mp.prepare();
        mp.start();
    } catch (Exception e) {}
}
```

`mp` is a global variable (so I can check whenever is playing or is null).

This is what happens when I click the button:

```
E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0xb40d7400
W/ViewRootImpl: Cancelling event due to no window focus: MotionEvent { action=ACTION_CANCEL, actionButton=0, id[0]=0, x[0]=676.58203, y[0]=318.10547, toolType[0]=TOOL_TYPE_FINGER, buttonState=0, metaState=0, flags=0x0, edgeFlags=0x0, pointerCount=1, historySize=0, eventTime=866058, downTime=860523, deviceId=0, source=0x1002 }
W/ViewRootImpl: Cancelling event due to no window focus: MotionEvent { action=ACTION_CANCEL, actionButton=0, id[0]=0, x[0]=676.58203, y[0]=318.10547, toolType[0]=TOOL_TYPE_FINGER, buttonState=0, metaState=0, flags=0x0, edgeFlags=0x0, pointerCount=1, historySize=0, eventTime=866058, downTime=860523, deviceId=0, source=0x1002 }
W/ViewRootImpl: Cancelling event due to no window focus: MotionEvent { action=ACTION_CANCEL, actionButton=0, id[0]=0, x[0]=676.58203, y[0]=318.10547, toolType[0]=TOOL_TYPE_FINGER, buttonState=0, metaState=0, flags=0x0, edgeFlags=0x0, pointerCount=1, historySize=0, eventTime=866058, downTime=860523, deviceId=0, source=0x1002 }
W/ViewRootImpl: Cancelling event due to no window focus: MotionEvent { action=ACTION_CANCEL, actionButton=0, id[0]=0, x[0]=676.58203, y[0]=318.10547, toolType[0]=TOOL_TYPE_FINGER, buttonState=0, metaState=0, flags=0x0, edgeFlags=0x0, pointerCount=1, historySize=0, eventTime=866058, downTime=860523, deviceId=0, source=0x1002 }
E/MediaPlayer: error (1, -2147483648)
I/Choreographer: Skipped 1806 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
```

The first one happens when I change the activity with the intent; the other ones, when I press the button for the sounds.

I already have the permission in the manifest.

EDIT: This is the full class:

```
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;

public class activity_2 extends AppCompatActivity {   
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_activity_2);
    }

    public void start_sound(View v) {

        String url = "<MY_URL>";
        MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();
        try {
            mp.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
            mp.setDataSource(url);
            mp.setOnPreparedListener(this);
            mp.prepare();
            mp.start();
        } catch (Exception ignored) {
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the method `prepareAsync()` on your media player since you are streaming the music. Just change that `mp.prepare()` and test it.

It seems as if you didn't implement the `onPreparedListener`. Implement this interface and call the `mp.start` inside the `onPrepared()` it should be fine.

Make sure your second activity implements `MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener`

Some other interfaces you can implement are `onErrorListener,  onCompletionListener`

Comment: Changed, now it gives me
`E/MediaPlayer: stop called in state 0
E/MediaPlayer: error (-38,0)
E/MediaPlayer: stop called in state 4
E/MediaPlayer: error (-38,0)
W/MediaPlayer: mediaplayer went away with unhandled events
E/MediaPlayer: error (-38,0)
E/MediaPlayer: error (1,-2147483648)`

Comment: I've seen it, but i can just use it calling android:onClick from the xml file

Comment: The idea here is to make sure that the media player is in the correct state before you call ``start()` on it. It must be in `prepared state`. That's why the method need to be called on receive of the prepared listener.

Comment: Ok then, what should i put in `mp.setOnPreparedListener(___)`?

Comment: Since your activity implements the interface, put `this`.

Comment: `Error:(45, 15) error: method setOnPreparedListener in class MediaPlayer cannot be applied to given types;
required: OnPreparedListener
found: activity_2
reason: actual argument activity_2 cannot be converted to OnPreparedListener by method invocation conversion`

Comment: Can you provide your class signature or the activity itself

Comment: It should be like this 
`public class activity_2 extends AppCompatActivity implements MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener {`

Then you can use `this` in `mp.setOnPreparedListener(this)`

Also, don't forget that you should use `mp.prepareAsync()` to prepare the media player and only call start on it inside the `onPrepared()` methos.

Comment: I did it, implemented the onPrepared method, still doesn't work, says i start it in state 4 and then 2 errors occur

Comment: I think it would be best to debug the full activity code then.

Answer (score 0):

I think you check media player object before initialisation that's the problem

```
  if (mp != null)
    {
        mp.stop();
        mp.release();
        mp = null;
    }
```

Make sure initialise  media player object before using.

```
      mp=new MediaPlayer();

 if (mp != null)
    {
        mp.stop();
        mp.release();
        mp = null;
    }
```

Comment: Same problems, i had MediaPlayer mp as a global variable, so i can check when it was still playing (so that if i spam click the button it doesn't create 1000 sounds).

Anyway i get the same error.

Comment: if you are using `prepareAsync()` then you must be surrounded it by try and catch block.

Comment: Everything is surrounded by a try-catch block

Answer (score 0):

You can do a thing like this:

```
public void play(){
    playButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.stop);
    player = new MediaPlayer();
    playing = true;
    player.setWakeMode(context, PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK);
    player.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
    player.setOnCompletionListener(this);
    player.setOnErrorListener(this);
    player.setOnPreparedListener(this);
    try {
        player.setDataSource(path);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    player.prepareAsync();
}

public void stop(){
    playButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.play);
    playing = false;
    player.stop();
    player.reset();
    player.release();
    player = null;
}
```

For my media player i created a custom listener, where button switches play/stop function (and imageresource).
You should use prepareAsync() and put the start in OnPrepared.

```
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    if (!playing) {
        play();

    } else {
        stop();

    }
}

@Override
public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
    playButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.play);
    mediaPlayer.stop();
    mediaPlayer.reset();
    mediaPlayer.release();
    //player = null;
    playing = false;
}

@Override
public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer, int i, int i1) {
    Log.i("Error","found");
    mediaPlayer.stop();
    mediaPlayer.reset();
    mediaPlayer.release();
    //player = null;
    playing = false;
    return false;
}


@Override
public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
    Log.i("mediaplayer","preparato");
    mediaPlayer.start();

}
```

The error you have, if you are playing external audio in sd, is connected (in my case it was) to the incorrect path with devices with no external sd card, so pay attention to the path you gave